# window.setTimeout(function() { not working with Google Maps Marker / XML

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have an issue to show markers from my DB to "fly in" individually.

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: '<?php echo PATH;?>ajax/map_process.php',
            success: function(data){
                $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
                     //Get user input values for the marker from the form
                      var name      = $(this).attr('name');
                      var address   = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('address') +'</p>';
                      var type      = $(this).attr('type');
                      var point     = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')),parseFloat($(this).attr('lng')));

                      //call create_marker() function for xml loaded maker
                      window.setTimeout(function() {
                      create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, false, "http://sanwebe.com/assets/google-map-save-markers-db/icons/pin_blue.png");
                      }, 1500);

                });
            }
        });
```

The resulting XML:

```
<markers>
 <marker name="PLUS Berlin" address="Warschauer Platz 6" lat="52.503699" lng="13.448671" type="10245"/>
 <marker name="Minus Hotel" address="" lat="52.520007" lng="13.404954" type="0"/>
</markers>
```

The create_marker function:

```
//############### Create Marker Function ##############
function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc,  InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconPath)
{                 
//new marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: MapPos,
    map: map,
    draggable:DragAble,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title:"Hello World!",
    icon: iconPath
});

//Content structure of info Window for the Markers
var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
'<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
'<h1 class="marker-heading">'+MapTitle+'</h1>'+
MapDesc+ 
'</span>'+

'</div></div>');    


//Create an infoWindow
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
//set the content of infoWindow
infowindow.setContent(contentString[0]);


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker); // click on marker opens info window 
});


if(InfoOpenDefault) //whether info window should be open by default
{
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
}
```

From what I understand this code should let the markers fly in one by one. Well, it doesn't they come all at once... Where should I put the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the markers are being created at the same time (1.5 seconds after the XML is processed).

If you want them to drop at different times, change the delay.

```
i++
window.setTimeout(function() {
  create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, false, "http://sanwebe.com/assets/google-map-save-markers-db/icons/pin_blue.png");
}, (1500+(i*500)));
```